# Compositor to VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

newbie here.

I've been having trouble getting the video I chroma-keyed (in the compositor, of course) to show up in the VSE.   After reading several of the answers to similar problems people have had, I figured out that I need to use the "scene" strip in the VSE.

Problem is, that only creates a strip displaying the output from the 3D full view, which I did not use at all.

In short, how do I save ONLY the scene from the compositor, without simply getting the 3D view?

Comment: Did you enable the Compositor in the Render settings?

Comment: Yes, Post Processing > Compositing is checked.

Comment: In the VSE preview window (with the cube image) open the window properties and turn off OpenGL render. You should see the proper scene render instead.